# Solving Equations using C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created a solution to solve cubic and quadratic equations. It worked well but after making some changes, it doesn't give a result and I feel it goes in endless loop.

I need your advise. The solution files are provided in the link below:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtLIyiEKfISSpFiHN5AG1WI68dmY?e=0oma3v

Thank you in advance,

Regards

Comment: So learn about the debugger: add a breakpoints, step through your loop and investigate the values. Did everything change as per expectations? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Check this piece of code in `Form1.cs`. Your loop relies on `eq1` and `eq3` that are not modified inside the loop's body.

```
double up = 5; double dow = -5; double sol = 0.5 * (up + dow);
double eq1 = a * (Math.Pow(dow, 3)) + b * (Math.Pow(dow, 2)) + c * (dow) + d;
double eq2 = a * (Math.Pow(sol, 3)) + b * (Math.Pow(sol, 2)) + c * (sol) + d;
double eq3 = a * (Math.Pow(up, 3)) + b * (Math.Pow(up, 2)) + c * (up) + d;

while (Math.Abs(Math.Abs(eq1) - Math.Abs(eq3)) > 0.0001) {
  if (eq1 * eq2 < 0 || eq2 * eq3 > 0) {
    dow = 1 * dow;
    sol = 0.5 * (dow + sol);
    up = dow + 2 * (sol - dow);
  } else {
    up = 1 * up;
    sol = 0.5 * (up + sol);
    dow = up - 2 * (up - sol);
  }
}
```

You should recalculate them to make the loop exitable.

```
while (Math.Abs(Math.Abs(eq1) - Math.Abs(eq3)) > 0.0001) {
  if (eq1 * eq2 < 0 || eq2 * eq3 > 0) {
    dow = 1 * dow;
    sol = 0.5 * (dow + sol);
    up = dow + 2 * (sol - dow);
  } else {
    up = 1 * up;
    sol = 0.5 * (up + sol);
    dow = up - 2 * (up - sol);
  }

   // Assuming that you want to use the previously used formulas:
   eq1 = a * (Math.Pow(dow, 3)) + b * (Math.Pow(dow, 2)) + c * (dow) + d;
   eq3 = a * (Math.Pow(up, 3)) + b * (Math.Pow(up, 2)) + c * (up) + d;
}
```